# Add annotation with bundled entity in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I have a some entities in a Symfony bundle which has its own field configuration in the bundle.

For example: *FOSUserBundle*.

Now, I want to add some more configuration through annotation or xml.

For example: I want to apply some serialization parameters or Assert validation or Gedmo parameters. How can I achieve this without rewriting the whole entity?